# Recover Console Text Output after Using fbi App to display image on /dev/fb0

Tags: raspbian, linux, framebuffer

I am not using X and I'm using fbi to display an image on the /dev/fb0 framebuffer device. When I boot up my Pi, I see all the usual text and it boots up to where I can log in on the console. After I use fbi like this:

```
fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb0 -a myimage.png
```

My image is displayed and replaces the text.

How do I 'discard' the image painted in fb0 and recover my text session so I can type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man fbi`:

> **COMMAND USAGE**
>
> **ESQ, q** Quit.

I think that should be "ESC" -- anyway, lots of informative stuff in the man page.

In case you are unaware, there are 6 virtual terminals (VTs) with log-in prompts created at boot, but only the first one is where init messages appear.  You can access these via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1-6</kbd>.

Which I think you know since you are using `-T 2`, making it sort of a strange question...

Answer (score 1):

Using Esc or Q to quit the 'fbi' app is great when it's still running.  What also works is sending SIGINT or SIGQUIT, i.e: `kill -2 $PID` or `killall -2 fbi` to interrupt (and quit), or `kill -3 $PID` or `killall -3 fbi` to tell FBI to quit.

I've run into issues where fbi *doesn't* cleanly quit, leaving /dev/fb0 filled with whatever image was displayed when fbi died/was killed.  You can display **over** it by running fbi again, but I haven't found a way to reset/re-initialize the framebuffer to provide a usable TTY on the console again.  That is, if you re-run your fbi command with a different image, it'll function and display, and even cleanly quit if you tell it to...then display the prior image still.

Comment: When I killall fbi , I get black screen . no console text